# Select column of data.table and return vector

Tags: r, data.table

Is it possible to select a column of a data.table and get back a vector? In base R, the argument `drop=TRUE` would do the trick. For example,

```
library(data.table)
dat <- as.data.table(iris)
dat[,"Species"] # returns data.table
dat[,"Species", drop=TRUE] # same
iris[, "Species", drop=TRUE] # a factor, wanted result
```

Is there a way to do this with `data.table`?

EDIT: the dat[,Species] method is fine, however I need a method where I can pass the column name in a variable:

```
x <- "Species"
dat[,x, drop=TRUE]
```

Comment: In newer `data.table` versions you can just say `dat[, Species]`.  You get a `factor` here _because you started with a factor_ from the `iris` data set.  (I didn't downvote.)

Comment: Try `dat[,get(x), drop=TRUE]` (not my downvote either)

Comment: @Karsten It helps if you start with the *real* question.  Try `colnam <- "Species"` followed by `dat[, ..colnam][[1]]`.  All this is, methinks, in the `data.table` FAQ ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `data.frame`, the default is `drop = TRUE` and in `data.table`, it is the opposite while it is done internally.  According to `?data.table`

> drop - Never used by data.table. Do not use. It needs to be here because data.table inherits from data.frame.

In order to get the same behavior, we can use `[[` to extract the column by passing a string

```
identical(dat[["Species"]], iris[, "Species"])
#[1] TRUE
```

Or

```
dat$Species
```

By using `[[` or `$`, it extracts as a `vector` while also bypass the `data.table` overhead

Answer (score 1):

In `data.table`, if you use column name to select columns, it depends how you write the name.

```
library(data.table)
dat <- as.data.table(iris)
dat[,"Species"] # returns a data.table
dat[["Species"]] # returns a vector, like selection of list elements.
dat[, Species] # returns a vector, use it like a variable.
```

To note, if you need a vector with some filters:

```
dat[petal.Length > 1, Species] # dat[["Species"]] can not use condition in i expression.
dat[petal.Length > 1, `#Species`] # for special name, use `` to quote such as `name@#$%^`
```

Answer (score 0):

See [`data.table` FAQ #1.1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#j-num). This comes as a feature since 2006.